# Analysis of final outcome

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5,rep(2,5)),value=c(0,-150,0,50,0,-120,0,30,0,-20),flag1=floor(runif(10)),flag2=rep(rbinom(5,1,.5),rep(2,5)),flag3=rep(rbinom(5,1,.5),rep(2,5)))
```

Each group starts with `0` value and the second row per group is the terminal value, this can be `>0 or 0<`.

For example group 1:

```
group value flag1 flag2 flag3
    1     0     0     0     0
    1  -150     0     0     0
```

I would like to find out which combination of variables values `flag1-flag3` results to negative `value` and  which to positive. This example above would indicate that having all `0` `flag1-flag3`at state 0 (row 1) would result to negative `value` = outcome (row 2). I would like to obtain the association per group and overall.

Comment: So, if the first row for each group has a `value` of 0, and otherwise the values of the other columns get repeated, then for each group the first row is redundant, right?

Comment: Well, the `value`=0 for each group is always 0 in row 1 so this is redundant, but the `flag1-flag3` could have values each either `0 or 1` in row 1 so this information is needed to determine the `value` being negative/positive in row 2, however in row 2 the values `flag1-flag3` are completely redundant, in row 2 the only relevant information is `value` (the outcome). Would just function `table` be sufficient to count the occurrences of `flag1-flag3` associated with `value>0` and `value<0` and divide this by number of observations...? So this would be probabilistic solution...

Comment: And what would you like to have as an outcome? A correlation coefficient of some sorts, or a distribution?

Comment: Well, not sure what would be the best approach this is really the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following as an example. I group by all possible values of `flag1-flag3` and calculate the probability distribution for positive or negative values for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

# remove redundant rows:
df <- df %>% filter(value != 0) 

# get all combinations of flat1-flag3 by grouping them,
# and then calculate the distribution:
df %>% group_by(flag1, flag2, flag3) %>% summarise(pos = mean(value > 0),
                                                   neg = mean(value < 0))
Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: flag1, flag2 [?]

  flag1 flag2 flag3   pos   neg
  <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0   0.0   1.0
2     0     0     1   0.5   0.5
3     0     1     0   1.0   0.0
4     0     1     1   0.0   1.0
```

If you are more looking for regression coefficients, you would probably want to do something like

```
 lm(value > 0 ~ flag1 + flag2 + flag3, data = df)
```

I am not sure this is what you were asking for, though. Just add it in case...

Just to point it out, you could get the above with the built-in function `ftable`, but I usually prefer `dplyr` as it returns a tibble, which is easy to work with.

Comment: I do not understand, second row..pos=0.5 and neg=0.5 and row 3 has flag2=1 otherwise 0 and pos=1 and neg=0. Would there be pure r solution for this? I have no idea about dplyr...

Comment: Yes, for the combination of `(flag1, flag2, flag3) = (0,0,1)`, half of the points are positive, and half of the points are negative. For the combination of `(flag1, flag2, flag3) = (0,1,0)`, all points are positive.

Comment: Hm, I have also NA in flag1-flag3 would this solution take care of these?

Comment: Yes, as an added group in the outcome.